# Fetch navigation from API in the next.js and render it at initial load of the page for better SEO

Tags: reactjs, next.js

i am very new to React/NEXT.JS and i guess i am facing a issue where i want to fetch data for my dynamic navigation bar, which is available on all the pages. I am using `context API` to set the value and fetch 1 time at the initial render of the whole document. Then it should show navigation items directly.

Here is how i am trying to do it.

```
import { createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Layout from "../components/layout";
import "../styles/globals.css";
import BasicProviders from "../helpers/BasicProviders";

export const NavContext = createContext();
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps, navigationItems }) {
  const [navitems, setNavitems] = useState(navigationItems);

  return (
    <NavContext.Provider value={{ navitems }}>
      <Layout>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
    </NavContext.Provider>
  );
}

MyApp.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
  const res = await fetch("http://www.myserver.com/navigation");
  console.log(res);
  return { navigationItems: res };
};

export default MyApp;
```

**Now i have folder structure like this:**

```
- components (in root directory of next.js)
  - layout.js
  - /Header
    - DesktopNav.js  <<<<<--------------- here i want to send my value of **navitems**
    - Header.js
```

This is how my `DesktopNav.js` is looking :

```
import Link from "next/link";
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import NavContext from "../../stores/NavContext";
import DesktopSubMenuLoop from "./DesktopSubMenuLoop";

export default function DesktopNav() {
  const { navitems } = useContext(NavContext);
  return (
    <nav>
      <DesktopSubMenuLoop navitems={navitems}></DesktopSubMenuLoop>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

Somehow it is sending the data to the component. But everytime i click on the Navigation Link it reloads the complete page. Not sure how i can achieve this. For the time being i am using `useEffect` to do achieve the same. But that is not SEO compatible.

**Problems need to be solved here:**

1. API should be called once for whole page. As the navigation will stay same for all the pages.
2. Page routing should be as smooth as it is with static  tags. Currently it reloads the page like a static HTML web page.

**Possible solutions i though of:**

1. is there any way i can fetch the `navitems` on _document.js and send to _app.js?
2. Calling the API on each page with getServerSideProps but that will make all of my pages non-static for internal pages as well at the build time.

Any solution i can get on this will be really helpful and thankful.

@juliomalves for you:

**MainNavigation Loop currently i am using useEffect to display the navigation, but as per my understanding its not good for SEO.**

You can check my loop here `DesktopSubMenuLoop.js`

```
import Link from "next/link";
import React from "react";

export default function DesktopSubMenuLoop({ navitems, isSubmenu = false }) {
  return (
    <ul className={isSubmenu ? "sub-menu-style" : ""}>
      {navitems.map((item, index) => (
        <li key={item.id}>
          <Link href={item.slug !== "/" ? `/${item.slug}` : item.slug}>
            <a>
              {item.title}{" "}
              {item.children && item.children.length > 0 && (
                <i className="icon-arrow-down"></i>
              )}
            </a>
          </Link>
          {item.children && item.children.length > 0 && (
            <DesktopSubMenuLoop
              key={item.id}
              navitems={item.children}
              isSubmenu={true}
            ></DesktopSubMenuLoop>
          )}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Comment: How are you handling client-side navigations? Can you show the code that renders the nav links? You have to use [`next/link`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link) to navigate between pages to avoid full page reloads.

Comment: Yes i am using that itself `next/link` to redirect from one page to another. Sure i can show you the full code as well.

Comment: @juliomalves i just added some segment for you. I just want to add a SSR to fetch all the navigation items and share across all the components/pages using context api

Comment: If you're using `next/link` then the pages will not fully reload. Are you sure the pages are fully reloading and not just re-rendering?

Comment: Yes 100% i have tried many many times. And seems like its reloading the whole page. If you want i can share the git repo as well with you.

Comment: @juliomalves i think i got the solution for **page-reloading** it was happening because of my browser issue. I just tried it on another laptop and seems to be working fine there. 

Now i just want to know last solution that what should i be doing that it wont fetch data on every new page redirect.

Comment: Because you're using [`getInitialProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps) in `_app`, the `navigationItems` will always be fetched on each navigation. If you don't want that behaviour, change your pages to [static generation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#static-generation-with-data), and fetch the navigation on each page inside `getStaticProps`.

Comment: @juliomalves how about Redux? can that help to solve the problem? As i am new to this. So i wanna go to Redux soon. But not sure if that can be helpful for me.